# Is it possible for selenium to find a label element by its "for" attribute using xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath, attributes

Is it possible for selenium to find a label element by its "for" attribute using xpath?

I'm testing a site that has 7 yes or no questions in row. The way the CSS is done, you click on the label instead of the input radio button. Normally I'd just find the element by text content, but there is a yes and no for each question.

I'm thinking that a work-around would be to do a javascript click on the input button to get around the "element is not visible" error that I get when trying to .click() the input directly, but I wanted to see if there was a better way to locate the label which is what users would actually be clicking.

*Edit for all of your who can't remember what a label element looks like. How would you select the middle one from this group?

```
<label for="superLongSetOfRandomCharacters123" class="common-to-all-buttons"> No </label>
<label for="superLongSetOfRandomCharacters345" class="common-to-all-buttons"> No </label>
<label for="superLongSetOfRandomCharacters456" class="common-to-all-buttons"> No </label>
```

More specifically, this is how they sit in the DOM

```
<ul class="list-view list-view-dividers">
   <li class="list-view-item">
      <div class="content">
         <div id="variableValue1" class="multipleChoice">
            <div class="form-row">
               <label>Question 1</label>
               <div class="form-row">
                  <table class="choices" id="randomlyGenerated-1">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <div class="ui-radio"><label for="randomlyGenerated1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off"> Yes</label><input id="randomlyGenerated1" type="radio" name="randomlyGenerated1" value="Yes"></div>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <div class="ui-radio"><label for="randomlyGenerated2" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off"> No</label><input id="randomlyGenerated2" type="radio" name="randomlyGenerated2" value="No"></div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="randomlyGenerated1-Error" class="component-error"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="list-view-item">
      <div class="content">
         <div id="variableValue2" class="multipleChoice">
            <div class="form-row">
               <label>Question 2</label>
               <div class="form-row">
                  <table class="choices" id="randomlyGenerated-2">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <div class="ui-radio"><label for="randomlyGenerated21" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off"> Yes</label><input id="randomlyGenerated21" type="radio" name="randomlyGenerated21" value="Yes"></div>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <div class="ui-radio"><label for="randomlyGenerated22" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off"> No</label><input id="randomlyGenerated22" type="radio" name="randomlyGenerated22" value="No"></div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="randomlyGenerated2-Error" class="component-error"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it is. In fact I did use them. But you need to show the html of the element you are talking about

Comment: One thing that is definitely *not* possible is for us to be able to *guess* what your app looks like. Have a read through [ask] and post more information.

Comment: Added some code for you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for selecting all labels with target 'for':
`label[@for='superLongSetOfRandomCharacters123']`

or you can leave `@for=''` blank for selecting all labels with any values (i.e. `label[@for]`)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the XPath-Option you are looking for would be "@". so in your case something like [...]/label/@for would return you that for-value, which you could then use to check where you are ;)

Cheers
D

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find_element_by_xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```
label = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="id_field"]')
```