# How to click a label without id with Selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing with this site here any https://www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680
And I'm trying after a few seconds that the page loads you must select the size and I can't select the size automatically with Selenium. Can someone help me?

Look, when it appears for you to select the size of the sneaker, I'm in Brazil and I select the size 40 of the sneaker, only if you inspect the "40" you will see that it is a label, and this label has no id, this label  is the following html code snippet:

```
<label for="tamanho__id40">40</label>
```

How could I click on this label in Selenium?

I currently have this code:

```
import datetime                                 
from selenium import webdriver          
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options                                           
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities
import DesiredCapabilities from selenium.webdriver.support.ui 
import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.common.by 
import By from selenium.webdriver.support 
import expected_conditions as EC                                
import time
                                            
option = Options()                              
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 2}}                                
option.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)   
# Navigate to url                                
driver.get"https://www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680")
```

**What would I have to add to be able to click on this label that has no id?**

Comment: this will help [Is it possible for selenium to find a label element by its “for” attribute using xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418206/is-it-possible-for-selenium-to-find-a-label-element-by-its-for-attribute-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You need to accept cookies

2 Use Selenium's explicit waits. To use them you will need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

3 Use reliable locators. I propose using this `xpath` locator for 40 shoe size: `//label[@for="tamanho__id40"]`

4 I added some `chrome_options` for dealing with this site.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/cosmic-unity-153-169-211-324680")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//label[@for="tamanho__id40"]'))).click()
```

Comment: My god, I had tried a lot before, including a code like yours, but I thought I had to remove the "//" from this code section `//label[@for="tamanho__id40"]` As I used javascript I didn't even pay attention and I thought this bar was for comment.